# how can i get html controls form html table in server side in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get html controls form html table in server side,asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7447583/how-to-get-html-controls-form-html-table-in-server-side-asp-net)

Can any body tell me how can i get html controls form html table in server side in asp.net? My code goes like this.

```
< table runat='server' id="CheckBoxList1">
  < tr>
   < td>< input runat='server' id='CheckBoxList1_1' type='checkbox' name='CheckBoxList1$1' value='1' />< label for='CheckBoxList1_1'>1
   < td>< input runat='server' id='CheckBoxList1_22' type='checkbox' name='CheckBoxList1$22' value='1' />< label for='CheckBoxList1_22'>22
   < td>< input runat='server' id='CheckBoxList1_43' type='checkbox' name='CheckBoxList1$43' value='1' />< label for='CheckBoxList1_43'>43 
< /table>
```

Thanks

Mohak